# Pulling HTML content from my wordpress site via JSON - jQuerymobile + Phonegap

Tags: jquery, iphone, xcode, json

I have been trying this for a week now I have not yet found any working solution I am quite stressed - If someone here could help that will be really good :)

**Summary**

- Creating Native app using jQuery Mobile & PhoneGap
- For iPhone first therefore i have xcode etc.
- I run a website using wordpress, I want to pull some content for select pages to display in this iPhone app.
- I have installed this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/

**What I have Done**
 - Created a nice working layout.
 - Installed It on my iPhone, works well (I am a iPhone developer).
 - Installed the plugin.

**Need Help With ...**
I am going to have a html table on my websites page I want the iPhone app to connect to the server and pull this html data and display it. (So if i change a price online it will reflect in the app).

However the entire page WILL NOT be generated from JSON (I know Apple wouldn't like it otherwise) for example header, footer and some other content is already coded.

**My code so far**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.myurlhere.com.au/api/get_page/?id=219/",

        success: function(json_results){
            console.log(json_results);

            $('#resultcontent')
            listItems = $('#resultcontent')
            $.each(json_results.results, function(key) {
                html = '<h3>Title Here</h3>';
                html += '<p>'+json_results.results[key].content+'</p>';
                listItems.append(''+html+'');
            });

        }
    });
})</script>

<div id="resultcontent"></div>
```

Can anyone see any issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

This threw me as well when I developed a PhoneGap application aswell, you're hosting the javascript on the phone I assume?

Try adding the parameter `datatype:"jsonp"` to the ajax call.

Also what you can do is inspecting the call from the PhoneGap application if you can open it up in something like FireBug and see if you get a response.

What I had to do was to add something like a `callback=?`parameter as well in the call to the URL.

The reason for adding jsonp format is because you can't issue ajax calls "cross domain" due to "Same Origin Policy"
  [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy therefore you have to use the jsonp tag. Read more about JSONP [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter).

and for jQuery [read here.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

I'll add some of my code for demonstrating purposes

```
var url = "/getSomeService.ws?customerid="+customerId+"&"+getLocalInfo()+"&callback=?";

var req = $.ajax({
    url : url,
    dataType : "jsonp",
    timeout : 30000
});
```

Good luck! I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply for the first time in DAYS I have been able to get it to connect and pull data ... I had to keep json BUT I had to add the callback=? as you mentioned :)

In Chrome browser If i 'inspect' the page It displays the object data however the Page is not displaying it :(

I Also get this error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
$.ajax.successcheapest.html:56
f.Callbacks.njquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.o.fireWithjquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
wjquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
f.ajaxTransport.send.d.onload.d.onreadystatechange"

Comment: I have no idea how to reply on this website sorry!

Comment: @BenDanyi edit your question and put the new changes there, that way it will be easier to understand the current state of the problem

Comment: Also, if the answer was to your liking and helped solve the original questions problem please accept it to help others like you! :)